# Free UI when retrieving Data Reader from database and indicate if data retrieving is completed C#

Tags: c#, async-await, ado.net, db2, ibm-midrange

Update 1:

```
  public  static DataTable GetDataTable()
        {
            using (var conn = new iDB2Connection(ConnectionString))
            {
                if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Open) conn.Close();
                conn.Open();

                iDB2Command cm = conn.CreateCommand();
                cm.CommandTimeout = 0; 
                cm.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cm.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM ORDER";

                var reader = cm.ExecuteReader();
                DataTable table = new DataTable();
                table.Load(reader);

                return table;
            }
        }
```

For button

```
  var t = Task.Run(() => dataTable = GetDataTable());
            t.Wait();
```

This does not free UI

//End Update 1

I have been trying but I could not understand the concept async well - please forgive me if the question is too simple.

I want to have a static method return a data reader - this can take reader mins as data has like 100k rows.

I read other questions from forum but I could not have a hand of it.

```
public async static Task<IDataReader> GetDataReader()
{
    using (var conn = new iDB2Connection(ConnectionString))
    {
        if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Open) conn.Close();
        await conn.OpenAsync();

        iDB2Command cm = conn.CreateCommand();
        cm.CommandTimeout = 0; //Avoid Data Limitation
        cm.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cm.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM ORDER";

        IDataReader reader = await cm.ExecuteReaderAsync();


        return reader;

    }
}
```

This method is called by a button

```
private async void btDoSomething_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        dataReader = await GetDataReader();
        //Let me know the dataReader is ready to use
}
```

There is no error but I don't know how to free my GUI as it is still being frozen when button is pressed.